# How can i change text colour of date to white?

Tags: php, html, css

```
<?php  

    echo "Today is " . date("Y/m/d") . "<br>";
?>
```

Anyone know how to change the colour of the date within echo? this prints out the date but only in default black, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
echo "<p style='color: red'>Today is " . date("Y/m/d") . "</p><br>";
```

Comment: Thanks that worked :)

Answer (score 1):

**Method 1:** You can use the line below. This is the simplest, but not the best way.

`echo "<span style="color: white;"> Today is " . date("Y/m/d") . "</span><br>";`

This basically prints out the date with a `<span>` tag around it (which has a color of white). This will make the text white.

**Method 2:** You can use a class.

`echo "<span class="anyClass"> Today is " . date("Y/m/d") . "</span><br>";`

```
.anyClass {
  color: white;
}
```